# Aggregator custom template file is not overriding the default one on Drupal 7

Tags: 7, theming, feeds

I have the Aggregator module enabled in Drupal 7. I have one feed and I'm showing it on the front page in a block. The block has under the feed a 'more-link'.

I want to change the text depending on the language and feed that I'm showing.

I added a copy of aggregator-summary-items.tpl.php to my theme folder and customized the file.

My problem is that is still showing the default one. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template file is either badly named or you put it in the wrong place, which can change depending on the theme.

To know which files may be candidates for templating, you can use [Devel Themer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) which was quite buggy last time I checked, but does a good job at listing candidate template files. Just enable it long enough to check them, and then get rid of it.

Comment: thx @Countzero, now i can change the block entirely and see what template file i need to change.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it uses template files.

Just override the function in your template.php.
(replace 'mytheme' with your theme's name).

```
/**
 * Returns HTML for an individual feed item for display in the block.
 *
 * @param $variables
 *   An associative array containing:
 *   - item: The item to be displayed.
 *   - feed: Not used.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
function mytheme_aggregator_block_item($variables) {
  // Display the external link to the item.
  return '<a href="' . check_url($variables['item']->link) . '">' . check_plain($variables['item']->title) . "</a>\n";
}
```